# Subview resizing at runtime - XCode 4.5.1 iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, view, subview

I'm trying to add a subview to a single-view iPhone app.  I drag a view onto the main view, set params:  x=180, y=20, Width=120, Height=120 and Xcode shows a nice square near the upper right corner of the screen.  When I run the app on either simulator or device, the square becomes a rectangle; I estimate the height value is about 1/5 the size displayed in Xcode while the width remains unchanged.

I've tried reducing the priority on the vertical constraints without any luck.

Any ideas on what I am missing here are appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you pin both the height and width in Interface Builder? (To do so, look under the Editor menu with the view selected.) You should be able to add constraints that specify the height and width of the view are both fixed at 120, and you can adjust those priorities to be 1000 ("required").

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you've created a new project (or a new xib in an existing project), and now you're testing the app on an iPhone 4S or earlier.  But by default, Xcode 4.5 (or later) creates a new iPhone xib with the top-level view sized for an iPhone 5, which has a taller screen.  When you run your app on a device with a smaller screen (or in the simulator configured as a such a device), the top-level view shrinks to fit and resizes its subviews.

If you **are not** using autolayout, you can change the subview's springs and struts so that the view's width and height are fixed and its left and bottom margins are flexible.

If you **are** using autolayout, you need to do the same thing by changing the constraints on the subview.

#### UPDATE

If you want to change the size at which Xcode displays the top-level view in the xib, select the view (or its view controller, if it has one in the xib).  Then choose View > Utilities > Attributes Inspector.  In the Attributes Inspector (right-hand side of the Xcode window), under the Simulated Metrics section, change the Size popup to Retina 3.5 Full Screen.

Keep in mind that if you do this, and you don't fix the springs'n'struts or the constraints, then you will have the opposite problem when you run the app on an iPhone 5: the top-level view will be stretched to fit the screen, and it will resize its subviews larger.

Comment: Rob - thanks for the explanation.  Indeed it is a 4S I am testing on and the main view size (which is locked) is bigger than the 4S screen.